# finding area using iterated integral

Tags: integration

I am trying to find the area enclosed between $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=\cos x$ between $x= \pi/4$ to $x = 5 \pi/4$. I got $\int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/5}\int_{\cos x}^{ \sin x} dydx$. But I am not getting the integral with order changed. please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are required to interchange the order of integration. Because the order you've selected is much easier.

In the opposite order, the region is defined by:

- for $-1 \leq y \leq -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, the inequalities $\arccos y \leq x \leq 2\pi - \arccos y$;
- for $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq y \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, the inequalities $\arccos y \leq x \leq \pi - \arcsin y$;
- for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq y \leq 1$, the inequalities $\arcsin y \leq x \leq \pi - \arcsin y$.

To evaluate the integral, you'll want to use the relation $\arccos y + \arcsin y = \pi/2$.